# Как сделать админку на полный экран?

Tags: админка, jquery, интернет-магазин, javascript

Привет, всем!

Сейчас доделываю интернет-магазин одежды и обуви. И вот в чем заключается мой вопрос - интересует возможность работать в админке всегда в полно-экранном режиме. Нужно также сделать так, чтобы магазин при входе в админку предлагает это сделать (работать в админке в полно-экранном режиме) нажатием кнопки в правом верхнем углу "в полный экран"
можно ли сделать, что бы при входе в админку - админка была уже развернута в полный экран?

Заранее спасибо всем, за помощь!

Comment: В идеале хотелось бы сделать этот скрипт кроссбраузерным. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, алгоритм действий для написания данного кода.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Любой нормальный контент-менеджер сидит в админке в 10 окон. Не творите фигню...)

А в остальном -

http://habrahabr.ru/post/184926/

http://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/